# Security StackExchange CTF team update #1

Tags: discussion, ctf

- I setup a [ctf](/questions/tagged/ctf) tag on meta. New posts should have that.
- We should all complete the challenges at http://smashthestack.org/. If you get stuck on a challenge, ask for help from other team members to learn from it. It is most important to try them first, then get help when stuck. That really does help with learning the mindset to functionally attack things as we'll need to do in competition.
- We have a private chatroom at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7384/security-se-ctf-team. We'll use that for competition planning and open it up at the end of a CTF, then create a new chat for the next time. This is in my mind the best blend of sticking with the StackExchange theory that chats should be open (except moderation issues) mixed with our need to not have other teams reading everything we type. We also have an IRC server setup. #SecSE-CTF on Freenode: chat.freenode.net:6667. We'll figure out what works best as time goes along.

Comment: You should replace `[tag:ctf]` with `[meta-tag:ctf]` for a correct link

Comment: Is the CTF on smashthestack.org supposed to be working? It's offline. Clicking another page, it got hacked by zmeu it seems (or is that supposed to be the challenge, avoiding getting 50 javascript alert()s?)

Comment: @Luc both the `io` and `blowfish` wargames are very good, I would recommend giving them a try while the `ctf` one is offline.